# Are there some wordpress themes that can't be edited with elementor?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I used the libretto theme on a wordpress website of mine [Here's the link to the theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/libretto/). I was trying to edit it with elementor to add a side bar but could not. I also could not see the "edit with elementor," option that is there on the tutorials. Are there some themes which limit the amount of editing that can be done and if there are could someone tell me the ones that don't.

Answer (score 0):

There are many themes that don't use elementor but they use other editors like WpBakery, Gutenberg and classic editor. I recommend **Calluna theme**- https://themeforest.net/item/hotel-calluna-hotel-resort-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/12996510?_ga=2.136889650.300517615.1579183340-575403741.1574945629

Other themes links that you may like
https://colorlib.com/wp/visual-composer-wordpress-themes/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to check to know which editor to use with which theme?

Comment: Most of the editors in WordPress can be used by all themes. There is a way if the theme developer has specified which editor to use but you can use any editor you like